# How can I aggregate values based on an arbitrary monthly cycle date range in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table as such:

```
# SELECT * FROM payments ORDER BY payment_date DESC;
 id | payment_type_id | payment_date | amount  
----+-----------------+--------------+---------
  4 |               1 | 2019-11-18   |  300.00
  3 |               1 | 2019-11-17   | 1000.00
  2 |               1 | 2019-11-16   |  250.00
  1 |               1 | 2019-11-15   |  300.00
 14 |               1 | 2019-10-18   |  130.00
 13 |               1 | 2019-10-18   |  100.00
 15 |               1 | 2019-09-18   | 1300.00
 16 |               1 | 2019-09-17   | 1300.00
 17 |               1 | 2019-09-01   |  400.00
 18 |               1 | 2019-08-25   |  400.00
(10 rows)
```

How can I SUM the amount column based on an arbitrary date range, not simply a date truncation?

Taking the example of a date range beginning on the 15th of a month, and ending on the 14th of the following month, the output I would expect to see is:

```
 payment_type_id | payment_date | amount  
-----------------+--------------+---------
               1 | 2019-11-15   | 1850.00
               1 | 2019-10-15   |  230.00
               1 | 2019-09-15   | 2600.00
               1 | 2019-08-15   |  800.00
```

Can this be done in SQL, or is this something that's better handled in code? I would traditionally do this in code, but looking to extend my knowledge of SQL (which at this stage, isnt much!)

Comment: Hi @crescent_ please can you show us what have you tried so far ? Thanks! Welcome to the Stack Overflow!

Comment: 260 should be 130 + 100 = *230*, shouldn't it?

Comment: @S-Man Yep absolutely, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c64bd7174938d835d9b486e313af6ba6)

You can use a combination of the `CASE` clause and the `date_trunc()` function:

```
SELECT 
    payment_type_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN date_part('day', payment_date) < 15 THEN 
            date_trunc('month', payment_date) + interval '-1month 14 days'
        ELSE  date_trunc('month', payment_date) + interval '14 days'
    END AS payment_date,
    SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM
    payments
GROUP BY 1,2
```

1. `date_part('day', ...)` gives out the current day of month
2. The `CASE` clause is for dividing the dates before the 15th of month and after.
3. The `date_trunc('month', ...)` converts all dates in a month to the first of this month

So, if date is before the 15th of the current month, it should be grouped to the 15th of the previous month (this is what `+interval '-1month 14 days'` calculates: `+14`, because the `date_trunc()` truncates to the 1st of month: `1 + 14 = 15`). Otherwise it is group to the 15th of the current month.

After calculating these `payment_days`, you can use them for simple grouping.

Comment: Thanks @S-Man, this is absolutely fantastic; appreciate the time you took to explain the logic for me.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the gotcha regarding the potential off-by-one bug. New stuff in this for me regarding date truncation, extraction and interval calculation. Cheers @S-Man

Answer (score 1):

I would simply subtract 14 days, truncate the month, and add 14 days back:

```
select payment_type_id,
       date_trunc('month', payment_date - interval '14 day') + interval '14 day' as month_15,
       sum(amount)
from payments
group by payment_type_id, month_15
order by payment_type_id, month_15;
```

No conditional logic is actually needed for this.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5048fbd9329f5028a7dd3e77a1a6b41a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: ahh yes! So simple. Thanks @Gordon

Comment: @crescent_ . . . Yes, it is simpler than the answer you have accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generate_series()` function and make a inner join comparing month and year, like this:

```
    SELECT specific_date_on_month, SUM(amount) 
      FROM (SELECT generate_series('2015-01-15'::date, '2015-12-15'::date, '1 month'::interval) AS specific_date_on_month) 
INNER JOIN payments 
        ON (TO_CHAR(payment_date, 'yyyymm')=TO_CHAR(specific_date_on_month, 'yyyymm')) 
  GROUP BY specific_date_on_month;
```

The `generate_series(<begin>, <end>, <interval>)` function generate a serie based on `begin` and `end` with an specific `interval`.